# Runtime error 440 cant parse when I add variable function "cells(i,3)" to "Filter"

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The macro works well to save attachments from file, but when i try to pass a variable "cells(i,3)" in filter restrict which matches the subject in outlook  it says cant parse,

```
Dim OlApp As Object
Dim OlMail As Object
Dim OlItems As Object
Dim OlFolder As Object
Dim J As Integer
Dim strFolder As String

Set OlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

strFolder = "xxxx\Emails" 'Change Extract to the folder name where you would like to have your attachements
Set OlFolder = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("xxx").Folders("Inbox").Folders("xxxx") 'Change folder names
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Worksheets("Email Details").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Lastrow

Dim Filter As Variant
Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%abc %' " & Cells(i, 3)
Set OlItems = OlFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)

For Each OlMail In OlItems

    If OlMail.attachments.Count > 0 Then
        For J = 1 To OlMail.attachments.Count
            OlMail.attachments.Item(J).SaveAsFile strFolder & "\" & OlMail.attachments.Item(J).Filename
        Next J
    End If
Next
Next i

Set OlFolder = Nothing
Set OlItems = Nothing

Set OlMail = Nothing
Set OlApp = Nothing

'MsgBox "Done"
```

Comment: `debug.? Filter`.

Comment: Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%abc %' " & Cells(i, 3)

Comment: this function doesnt allow me to pass a variable function, without cells(i,3) it works well

Comment: this filter function checks the subject line from the outlook mailbox to fetch attachment

Comment: error is runtime error 440 cannot parse

Comment: thanks tom, could you please advise what could be wrong with it

Comment: GSerg  any idea?

Comment: What is the exact string you're expecting to pass to `Filter`?  What is the value in `Cells(i, 3)` ?

Comment: yes cells(i,3) which is in my excel list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Private Sub filterWithVariable()

Dim Filter As String
Dim srchStr As String

Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%abc %' "
Debug.Print "filter with specified text: " & Filter

'srchStr = "abc " & Cells(i, 3)
srchStr = "abc " & "value in Cells(i, 3)"
Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & srchStr & "%'"
Debug.Print "filter with variable......: " & Filter

End Sub
```

Comment: You may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) **if you wish**.

Comment: See left side of the post. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/1571407